Chaotic one-dimensional system
Why can the solution of a one-dimensional equation of the form $$m\ddot{x}=F(x)$$ not be chaotic if $F$ is not explicitly time-dependent?
Multiplying by $\dot{x}$ and integrating with respect to time, we get
$$\frac12 m \dot{x}(t)^2 \underbrace{- \int_{x_0}^{x(t)} F(s)\,ds}_{=:V(x(t))} = \frac12 m \dot{x}(t)^2 + V(x(t))  = E ={\rm const.} \,, \tag{1}$$
where $x_0=x(0)$ and $E=\frac12 m \dot{x}_0$.
Before continuing, the question here is what does chaotic in this context really mean? Given two initial conditions, say $x_0,x_0'=x_0+\delta$ and $E,E'=E+\epsilon$ with $\delta,\epsilon>0$ being small, I guess you would have to show that the difference of the two solutions $|x(t)-x'(t)|$  stays arbitrarily small for all $t>0$, if their initial conditions are arbitrarily small.
Say for instance $E=E'$, so $\epsilon=0$. Then one can write the solution(s) implictly
$$\dot{x}(t)=\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(x))}\\
\Rightarrow \quad t=\int_{x_0}^{x(t)} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(s))}}=\int_{x_0'=x_0+\delta}^{x'(t)} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(s))}} \, .$$
This gives $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\delta} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(s))}} = \int_{x(t)}^{x'(t)} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(s))}} \, ,$$
so if $\delta >0$ is small, then the LHS is arbitrarily small and so must be the RHS, which implies $|x(t)-x'(t)|$ is small for all $t>0$.
If however $E\neq E'$ i.e. $\epsilon>0$, then it seems that this argument does not work, since one can not assure that the additional term of $O(\epsilon)$ stays small, since the integral $$\int_{x_0}^{x(t)} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{2m^{-1}(E-V(s))}}$$ may not be small.
Thanks for input.

I believe this question is answered by the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem. When there are fewer than 3 degrees of freedom, the only possible long-time dynamics are fixed points or simple orbits.

It's hard to give a general definition of “chaotic” (see Wikipedia for a commonly used one), but whatever it means, your definition of non-chaotic is much too restrictive. I assume that you're trying to negate the property of having sensitive dependence on initial conditions, but what you end up describing is some kind of very strong global stability property that not even a very non-chaotic linear system such as $(\dot x,\dot y)=(x,y)$ has.

Yes, indeed. But your example brings me back to my original considerations, that I discarded, because they did not appear to are of any help. Given a DE of any order, the equations reduced to first order are implicitly
$$y(t)=y_0 + \int_{0}^{t} f(s,y(s)) , ds , .$$
If $f$ satisfies a (global) Lipschitz condition with constant $L$, then going again with the two i.c. $y_0,y_0'$ one finds
$$|y(t)-y'(t)| \leq |y_0-y_0'|+\int_0^t |f(s,y(s))-f(s,y'(s))| , ds \leq |y_0-y_0'|+L\int_0^t |y(s)-y'(s)| , ds$$
and Gronwall then gives $$|y(t)-y'(t)| \leq |y_0-y_0'|e^{Lt} ,.$$
Not sure if it helps.

@whpowell96: Please do not post answers as comments.
